# How to perform type-cast of an array in GLSL?

Tags: casting, glsl

Is it possible to cast `vec4[1024]` to `float[4096]` in GLSL? Where can I find the specification  in the standard?

Comment: I don't think it possible with some simple cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [GLSL 4.40 specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf): `There is no typecast operator; constructors are used instead.`

Implicit conversions don't work for arrays either: `There are no implicit array or structure conversions. For example, an array of int cannot be implicitly converted to an array of float.`

Only other option would be to use an array constructor, but according to section `5.4.4 Array Constructors`, there is no array constructor that would take array parameters. So my understanding is that this is not possible.